# Firebase Datasnapshot returns null value

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, null

I want to retrieve this value from this node ("id"), and the value i get is null. I have googled so many solutions that this might have to do with asynchronous way or something, i guess?

This is the database, and the highlighted node is the value i would like to get:

[image: This is the database, and the highlighted node is the value i would like to get]

This is my code:

```
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            id = null;
            Query lastQuery = reference.child("Donation Request").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
            lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("id").exists())
                    {
                        id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(id) + 1;
                        id = Integer.toString(index);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It works!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        id = "1";
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It doesn't work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
```

Most appreciated if someone can help me out of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle this list by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren())`:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
id = null;
Query lastQuery = reference.child("Donation Request").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (snapshot.hasChild("id"))
            {
                id = snapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                int index = Integer.parseInt(id) + 1;
                id = Integer.toString(index);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It works!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                id = "1";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It doesn't work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors.
    }
});
```

A few more notes:

- Any use of `id` needs to happen inside `onDataChange`, or be called from there. Outside of that, you won't have any guarantees that `id` will have been assigned the value you expect.
- Using toasts for debugging is bound to become confusing. I highly recommend using `Log.d(...)` and friends, and studying the output (and its order) in the logcat output of your app.

Comment: Previously i wasn't aware of that Datasnapshot could return more than one possible result.